# What's a good Ruby development environment for the Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, ide, development-environment

I used to develop Java on the mac and it worked out well, combo of just using the terminal and IntelliJ.  What are good tools that run on the mac for doing Ruby development

Comment: Wow thanks for all the great answers!  Tough to pick just one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most of the Rails people develop on Macs and use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). As a result, TextMate has great support for Ruby *and* Rails, and is probably the best text editor to use for developing Ruby code on the Mac.

Answer (score 9):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) is a fantastic choice with lots of good features for debugging, refactoring, db browsing, source control and lots more.

Answer (score 6):

I use emacs, which has a fine ruby mode.

Comment: +1 to balance out the -1... this is a pretty subjective question, and many folks use emacs for development on the mac

Comment: -1 because it's 2009. :P

Comment: +1 because emacs works just fine in 2009, and has better support for a wider variety of development tasks than almost any other editor.

Comment: aquamacs is a good option on the mac if you aren't already a hardcore emacs nerd. It has normal mac key bindings out of the box

Answer (score 4):

I'll second/third the Textmate recommendation. Calling it a text editor is doing a bit of disservice. Start off with [this PDF](http://pragmaticstudio.com/rails/RailsTextMateCheats.pdf) that has some useful ruby/rails textmate shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

TextMate is an excellent editor, and is probably the best editor for Ruby code, as mipadi said. For an open source alternative, you could also try [Smultron](http://www.tuppis.com/smultron/). It's a bit rough around the edges, but it does the job quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I love TextMate although have been flirting with NetBeans. If you like a full-featured (aka bloated) IDE, give it a try. Pretty nice:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/Ruby

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains (the people behind IntelliJ) are working on an IDE specifically for Ruby on Rails: [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

if you like vim, adding onto it with fuzzyfilefinder (http://github.com/jamis/fuzzy_file_finder/tree/master) and rails.vim (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) plugins provides a really nice experience.

if you don't like vim, textmate is a decent text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You have used IntelliJ already? You should probably take a look at [the Ruby/Rails integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ruby_rails.html). It supports things like debugging, code analysis and refactorings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate is my favorite, but if you want code completion NetBeans is the best choice (Aptana/RedRails is outdated). Nightly builds of NB has a lot nicer OSX look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from *nix and you like Vim, then [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/).

If you're coming from any other OS and/or you don't like Vim, then [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).

TextMate is not free, but it's well worth the €39.  Trust me on this.  It will pay for itself many, many times over.

Answer (score 0):

MacVim or AquaEmacs are really the best choice for people developing on Mac who want to get the most out of their editor: for people less particular, Textmate is the way to go.

I always recommend VIM/Emacs to anyone because

1. They are not GUI based, which means everything they do is easily modifiable and scriptable
2. They are much more easily extendable
3. You can use them on a server
4. They are generally faster as there is less code in between you and the underlying operating system
5. They usually support more languages and varied development styles
6. They are much more transparent and understandable as to what they are doing
7. By necessity everything is accomplishable via a keyboard shortcut, so developing on them is faster

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), as recommended by a colleague (I don't have personal experience with it).

Comment: This is a bit misleading. Sublime Text 2 is free for evaluation, but a license should be purchased for continued use. Although it can be used in perpetuity without being paid for, it's good practice to support the developers of tools you benefit from, particularly when they make it easy to purchase a license.

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed that. Someone just told me to download it the other day for a quick programming exercise. I'll remove that part.